# Advanced Optimization google closure

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am facing issues in advanced Optimization mode of closure compiler.

My code worked fine when I had used basic optimizations, but after i removed all the warnings in advanced mode, it is giving me errors in external library files such as Kineticjs. It is either unable to find the methods in external library file(kinetic.js) or has renamed it to something else during advanced compilation mode.

What are the considerations that i should make so that i can move ahead and stop closure renaming the methods in external library file, specially i am having difficult time debugging the code in advanced mode.

my config file is as

```
{
    "id": "development",
    "inputs": "src/js/application.js",
    "paths": "src",
    "output-file": "development-compiled.js",
    "externs": "kinetic-externs.js",
    "level": "VERBOSE",
    "mode": "ADVANCED",
    "optimize": "closure",
     "closure": {
        "CompilerOptions": {
            "prettyPrint": true
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: The externs file is there to prevent the compiler from renaming things. Did you check to make sure the externs file you're using has all the functions you're calling? Maybe it was written based on an earlier version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `@export` annotation:

```
@export kinectic
```

and run it with the `--generate_exports` flag.

> Code that uses the @export annotation must either
>
> - include closure/base.js, or,
> - define both goog.exportSymbol and goog.exportProperty with the same method signature in their own codebase.

**References**

- [Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler: @export](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tag-export)
- [Use @public tag to prevent compression of symbol names](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=66&can=1&q=externs&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Modified%20Summary%20Stars)